# Check for Ruby Gem availability

Tags: ruby, package, rubygems

Is there a way to check if some gem is currently installed, via the Gem module? From ruby code, not by executing 'gem list'...

To clarify - I don't want to load the library. I just want to check if it's available, so all the `rescue LoadError` solutions don't help me. Also I don't care if the gem itself will work or not, only whether it's installed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

IMHO the best way is to try to load/require the GEM and rescue the Exception, as Ray has already shown. It's safe to rescue the LoadError exception because it's not raised by the GEM itself but it's the standard behavior of the require command.

You can also use the gem command instead.

```
begin
  gem "somegem"
  # with requirements
  gem "somegem", ">=2.0"
rescue Gem::LoadError
  # not installed
end
```

The gem command has the same behavior of the require command, with some slight differences. AFAIK, it still tries to autoload the main GEM file.

Digging into the rubygems.rb file (line 310) I found the following execution

```
matches = Gem.source_index.find_name(gem.name, gem.version_requirements)
report_activate_error(gem) if matches.empty?
```

It can provide you some hints about how to make a dirty check without actually loading the library.

Comment: Spot on. What I'll use is: `Gem.source_index.find_name('some_name').map {|x| x.name}` - it returns matching installed gems.

Comment: Use `$ gem list | grep YOURGEM` to check if the YOURGEM is present.

Comment: `GEM::LoadError` should be `Gem::LoadError`

Answer (score 39):

In Ruby 1.9.3 only there is also:

```
Gem.available?('somegem')
```

You can use regex expressions too. Handy if I want to allow 'rcov' and GitHub variants like 'relevance-rcov':

```
Gem.available?(/-?rcov$/)
```

Comment: This method is now deprecated:
NOTE: Gem.available? is deprecated, use Specification::find_by_name. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.

Comment: As of today, `Gem::available?` is gone. I'd suggest deleting this answer, or adding a note, so as to avoid misleading people.

Comment: This answer need be delete nowaday. (Ruby 2.5.1 Gem not available? method)

Answer (score 37):

Looking at the Gem API documentation, using [Gem::Specification::find_all_by_name](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Specification.html#method-c-find_all_by_name) to test for gem availability seems reasonable.

```
if Gem::Specification::find_all_by_name('gemname').any?
  do stuff
end
```

`find_all_by_name` always returns an array (of Specification objects), as opposed to `find_by_name` which raises an exception if no match is found.

Comment: This the best answer if you're using rubygems 1.8 or 2.0. No need for `rescue`. Alternatively, you can use `if` ... `.any?` to be more readable.

Answer (score 30):

Since Gem.available? is deprecated (argh!), you have to rescue again (double aaargh). Yes, find_by_name throws an exception if the gem is not found. So to be backwards-compatible with older rubygems, the common solution seems to be :

```
def gem_available?(name)
   Gem::Specification.find_by_name(name)
rescue Gem::LoadError
   false
rescue
   Gem.available?(name)
end
```

Note that the new method allows you to pass a specific version to see if that's loaded:

```
Gem::Specification.find_by_name('rails', '3.0.4')
```

Answer (score 6):

You could:

```
begin
  require "somegem"
rescue LoadError
  # not installed
end
```

This wouldn't, however, tell you if the module was installed through gem or some other means.

Comment: There are two problems here: I don't want to load the library (at least not yet) and I think that will fail if the code in "somegem" throws LoadError for some other reason.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code and it works smoothly.

```
def gem_available?(gem_name, version = nil)
  version.nil? gem(gem_name) : gem(gem_name, version)
rescue Gem::LoadError
  false
end
```

### Examples to use

Let's assume you have rack 1.9.1 installed.

```
puts gem_available?('rack') # => true
puts gem_available?('rack', '>=2') => # false
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see this anywhere here, but you can also pass fuzzy version strings to `find_by_name` and `find_all_by_name`:

```rb
Gem::Specification.find_all_by_name('gemname', '>= 4.0').any?
```