# ruby: code to install gem if missing

Tags: ruby, rubygems

is there some ruby code I can use to install a gem from a local file, if that gem is not installed?

i'm thinking it would look something like:

```
if !gem_installed("some gem name")
  system "gem install -l local_copy.gem"
end
```

i don't know if anything exists that lets me check for gems like this or not...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for Ruby Gem availability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032114/check-for-ruby-gem-availability)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking availability is covered in this [previous StackOverflow Quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032114/check-for-ruby-gem-availability)

```
begin
  gem "somegem"
  # with requirements
  gem "somegem", ">=2.0"
rescue Gem::LoadError
  # not installed
end
```

or

```
matches = Gem.source_index.find_name(gem.name, gem.version_requirements)
```

As for the install, it looks like [rails uses the system](http://rubyclub.com.ua/doc/api-rails-2.1-full/classes/Rails/GemDependency.html) for gem install also

```
 puts %x(#{cmd})
```

Comment: `GEM::LoadError` should be `Gem::LoadError`

Comment: You might want to use `Gem.clear_paths` after the system call to `gem install ...`, to actually load the gem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384756/after-installing-a-gem-within-a-script-how-do-i-load-the-gem

Answer (score 0):

This is my way of doing this

```
['json','date','mail'].each { |req|
    begin
        gem req
    rescue Gem::LoadError
        puts " -> install gem " + req
        Gem.install(req)
        gem req
    end
    require req
}
```