# Requiring an uninstalled gem doesn't fall to "rescue" in begin-rescue

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am dealing with a very minor issue here. I am simply trying to require some gems, and just simply revert to the code in the `rescue` block if the gems aren't installed. However, it's never reaching the `rescue` even though it's in a `begin`/`rescue` block:

```
begin
  ['net/http', 'getopt/std', 'pry','json'].each(&method(:require))
rescue
  puts "A gem required for this script is missing. It is installing now."
  `gem install getopt`
  ['net/http', 'getopt/std'].each(&method(:require))
end
```

When I run this script on a system that doesn't have the first gem, `net/http` installed, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from ./agent.rb:16:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- getopt/std (LoadError)
```

Shouldn't this fall into the rescue block? What am I doing wrong that's resulting in it not falling into the rescue block?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [How to rescue from a require "gem_name" when the gem is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061528/how-to-rescue-from-a-require-gem-name-when-the-gem-is-not-installed)

Just have to change `rescue` to `rescue LoadError` and that solves this problem. For whatever reason, I thought including just `rescue` without anything after it would catch *all*.