# How to check if a RubyGem is installed already?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, cocoa, macos, rubygems

I am writing an application for Mac OS X. It is a Cocoa application. Can I check if a specific RubyGem is installed from Cocoa, do I need to use NSTask or should I use the Ruby framework?

What is the best way to check this?

Comment: Here's a pretty simple way to do it using Ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032114/check-for-ruby-gem-availability

Comment: @Hans thanks, that's already 50% of the answer :)

Comment: I can't see how you'd do it in Cocoa, unless you knew for sure where the user's RubyGems directory was. You could also shell out, I suppose, but if it's possible to use Ruby I think the link I posted is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what the reason is for checking for the gem, it seems like it might be a good idea to shell out to a script you bundle with your application. Then have that script check for you. That way you can be sure to access the gem environment in a way that is as close as possible (or even identical) to the way the user will.

Using code like what Has Engel posted in that other SO thread looks like a good way to do it once you are out in the shell.